# React add images to existing map

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app where I fetch the item data from an API.

I'm mapping each item's data to a card in the react app.

```
this.props.item.map(item => {
      return <Card data={item.name} key={item.id}/>;
```

This works, however I want to add a corresponding image to each item in the array and I'm not sure what approach to take to add images to an existing map.

The images are stored in the public folder and not available via the API. I want the correct image to correspond to the correct data.

Eg. data="flowers" key="123" src="../images/flowers.jpg"

Thanks!

Comment: each `item` have an attribute that stores the image that it takes?

Answer (score 1):

Initially take the images from the public folder and add it to somewhere inside src say, src/assets/images. 
Then you will have to create an object corresponding to each data value. Then map the value to the image name.

```
var flower = require("../assets/images/flowers.jpg");
var cat =  require("../assets/images/cat.jpg");
var dog =  require("../assets/images/dog.jpg");
var dictionary={"flowers":flower, "cat":cat,"dog":dog}
```

now when you get response from API,

you can use inside the card component as,

```
<img src={dictonary[props.name]}/>
```

Comment: Can you pls accept the answer for stack overflow community if the answer worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a new prop named `src`, and use it with the name of the item:

```
this.props.item.map(item => {
     return <Card data={item.name} key={item.id} src={`${item.name}.jpg`}/>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an image to item.id map and there you can find image from your local.

example:

```
const imageIdMapper = {
  1: require("./<path to image belongs to id one>),
  2: require("./<path to image belongs to id two>),
  ...
}
```

then in your map

```
this.props.item.map(item => {
      return <Card data={item.name} key={item.id} image={imageIdMapper[item.id]}/>;
```